# Cant see change when I change material color and no differnce between Eevee and Cycles engine

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am new to blender, when I first started every thing was fine, I could see all changes I made to the material and switching render engine to the Cycles was working fine, then I saved my project and closed blender. When I reopened blender I couldnt see the colours, they were still there but just not appearing on the screen, also when changing the scene render engine from eevee to cyles nothing changed. I see the colours and the change in render engine when I rendered my model by pressing f12. I've already tryed restaring my project and re-installing blender. pls help

[image]

Comment: This is also explained in the very tutorial you're following, just watch it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

In the top right there are the 4 circles, the first is for wireframe view, solid view, lookdev view and last (the one you need) render view. Clicking this should display the material